# Como mudar a cor do Ion-item Input e da Barra do Android?

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Como faço para mudar de "azul" quando eu clico no input para a cor que eu desejo no ion-input? Eu só consegui alterar a cor do placeholder com:

```
*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;
}
```

Como faço para alterar a cor do "bar" do android onde fica os ícones?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa noite, Você pode utilizar o ionFocus para chamar uma função toda vez que o input estiver "em foco". Nesse caso, da pra mudar a cor do ion-input a partir dessa função(a implementação pode ser feita de diversas maneiras diferentes). Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -2):

Para alterar a cor de fundo do input no ionic 5 podemos utilizar o --background

```
ion-input {
 --background: red;
}
```

Para alterar a cor apenas quando selecionamos o campo, utilize os seletores hover e active. Veja um exemplo:

```
ion-input:hover {
  --background: red;
}
```

Mais detalhes podemos encontrar na documentação do Ionic que nos dá mais informações sobres os CSS que podemos utilizar com ION-INPUT:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para Alterar a cor da Status Bar podemos utilizar o plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar conforme sugerido pelo documentação do framework:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar

### INSTALAÇÃO

**CORDOVA**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install @ionic-native/status-bar
```

**CAPACITOR**

```
npm install cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install @ionic-native/status-bar
ionic cap sync
```

**ANGULAR**

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

constructor(private statusBar: StatusBar) { }

...

// let status bar overlay webview
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);

// set status bar to white
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
```